# have read or be reading

Tags: grammar

Can I use **present perfect** or **present continuous** with **"this month"** or other words like this week, this year?

Could you tell me the different meaning between them like the sentences below?

I **have read** three books this month.

I **am reading** three books this month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both mean different and I'm not sure you are looking for that.

> I have read three books this month - the process is finished. You are done with those books in this month. 
>   I'm reading three books this month - You are reading three books simultaneously in this month OR You plan to read them (and are sure).

Examples:

> I have read three books (in) this month - The last three books of HP series.
>
> I'm preparing for the civil service exams and reading three books this month (The General Knowledge Book, the Aptitude Book and Book for Reasoning) OR I am pretty confirmed to read those three books this month as I have an entrance exam of Civil Services. [You use present perfect for the future **if things are sure** - The train **is leaving** in 10 minutes].

So, if you want to mean that you are reading those books in *pipeline*, you may simply say:

> I plan to read three books this week/month/year

Or, as I said, if you are pretty confident and the **thing is sure**,

> I'm reading (will read) three books this week/month/year.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mualik V. for your help. I was confused that "have read" in this case might have the same meaning as "be reading".